# Why does this simple counting loop in assembly start behaving eratically when I add a random floating point instruction?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, floating-point, arm

I am working on a bare metal OS for the Raspberry Pi model B, which features an ARM1176-JZF-S processor. While working on implementing the sine function for a math library, I encountered something very strange, which I've whittled down to a small-ish minimum reproducible example.

The following code counts up from zero to four, and prints out each number with spaces in between:

```
    mov     r4, #0              // Initialize counter to 0

c_loop$:
    ldr     r0, =IntString      // Convert counter to a string
    mov     r1, r4
    bl      int_to_str

    ldr     r0, =IntString      // Print the string
    ldr     r1, =0x00000FF0     // (Green text on black background)
    bl      print

    ldr     r0, =Space          // Print a space
    ldr     r1, =0x00000FF0     // (Green text on black background)
    bl      print

    mov     r5, #0x1000000      // Pause for a beat
c_pause$:
    subs    r5, #1
    bne     c_pause$

    add     r4, #1              // Increment counter
    cmp     r4, #5              // Repeat until counter = 5
    blt     c_loop$

halt:                           // Wait forever
    b       halt
```

The functions `int_to_str` and `print` were both written by me, and work fine. To be clear, they are not printing to any kind of output stream; they just write pixels in the shape of numbers directly to a frame buffer, which I got from the GPU through the mailbox system. The label `IntString` is a space for me to store the conversion of the counter to a string so I can print it out, and the label `Space` points to a string that's just a single space. **This code works as intended** and I see the numbers displayed on the screen.

Here's what's odd. Have a look at this floating-point operation:

```
    vadd.f32    s2, s0, s1      // What the heck is happening here?
```

When I add this into the loop right before the line where I increment the counter, I get different behavior entirely. Rather than printing "0, 1, 2, 3, 4", I now I see "0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ..." repeating forever. Why is this happening? Why does the floating point instruction have any effect on this code at all?

**Important additional info:** A while ago, I was working on some code to draw a Mandelbrot fractal to the screen, using floating point arithmetic to do the calculations. Back then I believed that my Raspberry Pi had a Cortex A7 processor (which is what the newer models have) and I turned to the [Cortex A7 Floating-Point Unit Technical Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0463/f/DDI0463F_cortex_a7_fpu_r0p5_trm.pdf) which says that:

> To use the Cortex-A7 FPU in Secure state and Non-secure state, first define the NSACR and then define the CPACR and FPEXC registers to enable the Cortex-A7 FPU.

It gave the following code snippet to accomplish this task:

```
    MRC     p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 2
    ORR     r0, r0, #3<<10  // enable fpu
    MCR     p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 2

    LDR     r0, =(0xF << 20)
    MCR     p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 2

    MOV     r3, #0x40000000
    VMSR    FPEXC, r3
```

For some reason, this worked, and my Mandelbrot fractal appeared. Anyway, **this snippet is present the program I'm working on today**, directly above the code shown. When I remove it, I get *different* unexpected behavior. The program prints "0, 0, 0, ..." -- an infinite series of just 0's instead of 0's and 1's.

**More details:** My best guess about what's going on here is that the s0 and s1 floating point registers initially contain garbage, and that adding them together can raise an exception. This would explain a detail I haven't mentioned yet, which is that the code *occasionally* works even with the floating point instruction included -- maybe one time in five.

In order to test this theory, I tried setting all registers involved to zero right before the counting loop begins:

```
    mov     r0, #0
    vmov    s0, r0
    vmov    s1, r0
    vmov    s2, r0
```

And lo and behold, the loop worked again. However, as a further test, I decided to set both s0 and s1 to the maximum value a float can hold, reasoning that this should yield an overflow error and cause the unexpected behavior to return:

```
    ldr     r0, =0b01111111011111111111111111111111
    vmov    s0, r0
    vmov    s1, r0
    vmov    s2, r0
```

But this too leads to the correct counting behavior!

I'm at a loss for what's going on here. What's causing this?

**Update:** I've just noticed an issue. The code I'm using to assemble .s files into .o files is this:

```
    arm-none-eabi-as -o $@ $< -mfpu=vfpv4 -mcpu=cortex-a72 -mfloat-abi=hard
```

But this has two issues. One, the `vfpv4` is incorrect as the model B features VFPv2, and two, `cortex-a72` is incorrect as the model B features an ARM1176-JZF-S.

Fixing the first of these two issues doesn't change any of the behavior mentioned above (I re-tried each example and got the same results). The second issue seems more serious, however, since the man page for `arm-none-eabi-as` doesn't list the model B's processor type as one of the options. I will investigate further and post an update once I know more.

Comment: Are you saying an FP math instruction clobbers integer registers?  Perhaps you have software FP emulation that doesn't properly save/restore integer state?  (And that emulation runs when you don't enable the hardware FPU?)

Comment: Are you able to single-step the code with a debugger, to see what the flow actually is and what happens to the registers?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm running the code on a real Raspberry Pi without an operating system. Does that preclude using a debugger, or is there some way I could still do it?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm asssembling this with hardware floats enabled, but your comment made me look at my Makefile again and I may have found a (the?) issue. I'll update this in a minute.

Comment: If you're running this on bare metal, not under an OS, you need to have the HW programmed in a way that matches what you're telling the compiler you have.  `gcc -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon` or similar options tell it that it can *use* hardware FP instructions.  Not to make it emit extra code to *enable* them for you.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've just updated the question with the relevant line from my Makefile. I've got options like those already in there, but, well, see the update. There's another option I have that's troubling and which might be the source of my problems.

Comment: Like I said, those built-time options are irrelevant.  That's not going make GCC run a `VMSR` instruction as part of startup (I think).  Those `-m` options control GCC's code gen when it's compiling C to asm, not assembling your hand-written asm.  (Well it might reject some instructions that aren't enabled.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I misread your comment, I had it backwards. But I've got code that (supposedly) enables the floating point unit anyway -- see the section that begins "Important Additional Info". I've even had floating points working in the past to generate a Mandelbrot fractal -- they just seem to be acting strangely in this new context.

Comment: Oh, I missed that when skimming your question; it's pretty long and hard to glean the essential points quickly.  So you are using init code to put the CPU in the state you're telling GCC about.  So yes, if that code does what it's supposed to then you should be able to use FP instructions without them breaking integer registers.  Re: `as` options: Unless there are different encodings for the same insn depending on CPU (doubtful), `-mcpu=cortex-a72` should just be limiting which instructions it lets you use; i.e. stop yourself from using insns your HW doesn't support.  A too-new CPU is fine.

Comment: Also make sure your functions that you did not show don't accidentally use the floating point registers.

Comment: Did you check the FPU state to make sure FP exceptions are masked?  Unmasked exceptions jumping to random handlers could be a problem, and would explain the behaviour you're seeing where zeroing the FP regs so you're always doing `0+0` makes it work.  `FLT_MAX + FLT_MAX` overflowing to +Inf is a different exception than getting a NaN or other invalid operations, or underflow, so maybe only some exceptions are accidentally unmasked?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the tip about the `as` options. As for unmasked exceptions, I wondered if it might be something like that, but my understanding of low-level exception stuff is pretty poor. Where do I check to see if those exceptions are masked?

Comment: I don't know that level of ARM details; presumably that's one of the things your FPU-init code sets.  So look up in the ARM manuals for what those bits mean in the control registers you're writing.  Another way to test the FP-exception theory would be to single-step your code in a debugger.  e.g. in qemu if you don't have bare-metal debugging on real hardware.  A debugger is an essential tool for asm development; many things go from being opaque to trivial when you can single-step and look at registers change, including stepping into exception handlers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the advice. I'll have a look in the manual. qemu nominally only supports the Raspberry Pi v2, but I'll give it a whirl -- you're probably right about a debugger being essential.

Comment: Programming in asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded.  If everything isn't lined up just right, it crashes.  So many different problems have the same failure mode, etc.  I mean people did write and debug programs before computers were powerful enough to *have* debuggers, but it took way more effort.  And like you're seeing here, you waste time trying random theories about what might be wrong instead of just watching it happen.

Comment: Also, any floating point instruction will fault if the fpu is not enabled (something you do need to do in bare metal on this platform).  Both the arm docs and if you look at the raspberry pi baremetal forum you will find code from myself and many others that show you how to do this.

Comment: Being bare metal I assume you are managing r4, r5 and preserving them or have your own calling convention you are using.  a "complete" example would have been nice, including all of the code needed to reproduce not just fragments.  using those registers without preserving them even adding a single instruction can change the rest of the binary in a way that will make this work/fail.  a full example would have helped here.

Comment: Have you disassembled the code to see/confirm what you wrote is what you got...another thought is depending on how you did your exception table you might not have enabled the fpu you might be hitting a handler and basically running your program again and again or part of your program again and again...

Comment: claiming your functions are not part of the problem is like claiming the floating point instruction cant be part of the problem.  Everything is suspect until solved, could be a combination of things that are happening which each part in isolation works fine.

Comment: what if you add a nop there instead of the floating point instruction, what happens then?

Comment: it is straignt forward to get openocd connected to the arm11 on the older pis (and the pi zero) with some additional hardware about $15 - $20 at adafruit, cheaper if you want to gamble on ebay.  the latter pis with the multiple cores this becomes more difficult.   then telnet in and you can load programs, stop and start, single step dump stuff, whatever.  after openocd 0.9.0 arm11 support gets flakey so use 0.9.0 and myself and others have code to enable the jtag on the pi...Note you will in general get much better support on the pi site than here for bare metal arm work.

Comment: check the disassembly there are two floating point syntaxes (well four or more, but) and two of them produce the same instructions, if you are using the right instruction it should encode right with the assembler, but thats why you should check the disassembly.

Comment: @old_timer: I haven't done bare-metal development for real, but in user-space it seriously speeds up development to know which instruction faulted and what value was in a register.  In user-space debuggers can be perfectly non-intrusive, like in a VM. But sure with enough familiarity with asm, you can work without a debugger.  Debuggers are fantastic for catching brain-fart or beginner mistakes, though.  So many of the asm questions we get on SO are basic beginner stuff that would have been easily spotted with a debugger, and thus are a waste of space and time (unlike this question).

Comment: @old_timer Yes, my calling convention is that callees must save and restore all registers except r0-r3. (I read somewhere that this is standard, but now that you mention it, I have no idea how widespread it is.) I haven't done anything with the exception table as I don't even know how to do that -- I'm a noob at bare metal. Point taken about claiming my functions work; I should have said they appear to work. I would have included more code, but even in my MWE there was rather a lot of it (because of drawing text to a screen). Is there a way to add lots of code without making the question huge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this now. [This](https://github.com/octachrome/piberry/blob/master/doc/FloatingPoint.md) web page explains what needs to be done to set up floating point numbers, and I was missing this part of the process:

```
    @; load the status register
    fmrx    r0, fpscr
    @; enable flush-to-zero (bit 24)
    orr     r0, #0x01000000
    @; disable traps (bits 8-12 and bit 15)
    bic     r0, #0x9f00
    @; save the status register
    fmxr    fpscr, r0
```

The page explains:

> The default floating point mode on the ARM11 is to implement the most common floating point operations in hardware, and delgate to software for special cases. This is done by raising an unsupported operation exception, called a trap, in which you the programmer are supposed to figure out what went wrong (e.g., an underflow), calculate the correct result, and resume the program.
>
> If, like me, you don't feel like implementing a bunch of floating point operations, there is an alternative: RunFast mode, or Flush-to-zero mode (which nearly means the same thing). This is a pure hardware floating point implementation which is not-quite IEEE 754-compliant. [...]

I haven't implemented any such handlers, so it looks like this configuration is what I need. I don't have a full mental picture of why this was causing the exact problem I was having, but I'm no longer surprised that there *was* a problem.

Comment: That makes sense; on some x86 hardware producing a [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) result (exponent field = 0) takes a microcode exception and is super slow, because the FPUs are optimized for latency in the common case.  On that ARM CPU they apparently take it a step further in keeping the HW simple and punt that FP assist to *software*.  You can set the HW to just flush subnormals to zero instead of taking an exception.  Other cases (flushing overflow to +Inf, or invalid to NaN) can be handled more easily in HW.

Comment: Anyway, presumably the handler address is loaded from memory somewhere, and if you didn't do anything about it then the CPU was jumping *somewhere*, and eventually returning or not, I forget what symptoms you described.  Note that the bit-patterns for subnormal numbers are small integers, so if something leaves random small integer values in the FPU registers, you'll get these exceptions.

Comment: Ah, so *that's* what flush-to-zero means. I'm learning something new every day from this undertaking.